# Which code relates the calendar in wordpress widget with post?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress default  calendar in widget displays the post published on that particular day if we click a date.I need the code which performing this action.

Answer (score 1):

it is in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php` in the class `WP_Widget_Calendar`

In there you will find a call to the [`get_calendar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_calendar) function. `get_calendar` itself is in: `wp-includes/general-template.php` It should be around line 1074.

Just putting `get_calendar()` anywhere will generate the calendar with click-able posts just as the widget does. Remember there have to be posts to be click-able.

Tested on multiple sites.

Comment: I dont want to change the default behaviour but i just need the code which performs the action of displaying post if we click a date in widget calendar.

Comment: @RamaPriya, have you *actually checked* the file janw is pointing you to? Or do you want us to copy paste it here?

Comment: @RamaPriya Did you even read my **whole** answer? you need `get_calendar` which does the same as the widget

Comment: I checked that function get_calendar and even checked the entire file but i cant find the exact line which performs the action of displaying post, if we click a date in widget-calendar.It'll be useful if i get the exact code which performs this action and also mention in which file that code is present

Comment: @RamaPriya I've clarified my answer. But still all you need is `<?php get_calendar() ?>` to display the calendar, clickable and all.